# How do i find the most frequently occuring category for each unique customer from the table which contains multiple entries for customer?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, feature-engineering

I have a dataset with 30k unique users with each customer having multiple transactions. I aggregated the dataset with one record per user and containing aggregated information such as average transaction amount, last visit date etc. I have a lot of categorical variables. I need to find the most frequently occurring category per each customer and store it in the aggregated data set.How do I do that in Python ?

[image: This is the original dataset]

[image: This is the aggregated dataset]

Same user has only one record. I need to check the most frequently occurring category of that user in the categorical feature PRODUCT_DESC.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['INITIAL_EMAIL_KEY'], df['PRODUCT_DESC'])` gives you the count of each category per user. You can then use `.idxmax(1)` to find the corresponding category.

Comment: Also, post your data as text, do not just include the picture.

Comment: Thanks. I want to do the same for every categorical variable. Can I use a for loop or do I need to do this manually? @Quang Hoang

Comment: You have others categorical columns than `PROC_DESC`? Yes, you can do a loop.

Comment: Yes from PROC_DESC there are 8 features that are categorical. I need to do the same for all these features.

Comment: Then no. You only do it once, it should give you the correct answer.

Comment: Somehow my records are getting deleted by this operation. My initial records were 33k. After doing the same operation on all the categorical variable it became 16k. Am I doing something wrong? @Quang Hoang

Comment: Somehow my records are getting deleted by this operation. My initial records were 33k unique user's records. 1600 records were deleted. When I did the same operation on other categorical features, the records deleted by half and became 16k records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200309/discussion-between-asspsss-and-quang-hoang).